# How can I make Github desktop detect changes in STS?

Tags: spring-boot, github, repository, github-desktop

I am trying to link between Github desktop and STS so that whenever I make changes to my project in STS, Github desktop can detect them.

I created a new repository from Github desktop and published it.
Then I copied the url from Github website to clone the repository to STS.
After that, I right-clicked the project I want to share, clicked Team -> Share Project.
The result looks like the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IgLx.jpg).

But Github desktop can't still detect the changes I made in STS.
Maybe something is wrong with the working tree(image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm23p.jpg)), I guess?

Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IgLx.jpg)

[enter image description here 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm23p.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding "STS" ([Spring Tools Suite](https://spring.io/tools)), this is based on Eclipse and its Git plugin.

So try instead to:

- manually (command line) clone the GitHub repository.
- *Then* import the local clone to STS, following from instance "[How to import a GitHub project into Eclipse](https://github.com/collab-uniba/socialcde4eclipse/wiki/How-to-import-a-GitHub-project-into-Eclipse)" or JBoss documentation "[Importing as a General Project](https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/git_import_projects.html)"

The working tree should be better recognized.

Comment: Adding my project as local repository in Github desktop worked. Thanks a million!